# Using ginkgo with different go versions

Tags: go, ginkgo

I'm using go with multiple version as stated in this doc https://go.dev/doc/manage-install

```
go install golang.org/dl/go1.10.7@latest
go1.10.7 download
```

And I'm also using ginkgo, which I installed like this: (based on https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/#installing-ginkgo)

```
go install github.com/onsi/ginkgo/v2/ginkgo@latest
```

I can run a ginkgo test suite like this:

```
ginkgo ./...
```

However, this uses my main go version. I would like to use ginkgo to test with another version of go. Currently, the best I can do is to run the ginkgo tests with `go test`

```
go1.10.7 test ./...
```

Can I make `ginkgo` use different version of go to test with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on their source code, they just use the command `”go”`, so your options are:

1. Temporarily rename `go` to `go.bak` and then rename `go.10.7` to `go` (e.g. using `mv`)
2. Open up a pull request to allow support for overriding the path to the Go executable (via an environment variable, for example)
3. Do what you’re doing now

---

Source: https://github.com/onsi/ginkgo/blob/master/ginkgo/internal/compile.go

Relevant code:

```
func CompileSuite(suite TestSuite, goFlagsConfig types.GoFlagsConfig) TestSuite {

    ...

    cmd := exec.Command("go", args...)
```